# compiling ffmbc on OS X with libvorbis

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, installation, gcc

I've installed libvorbis, and that all seemed to go fine, and now I'm trying to install FFmbc with --enable-libvorbis but it fails with Error:libvorbis not found. In the config.log produced I get:

```
ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libvorbisenc.a, file was built for unsupported file format which
is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libvorbis.a, file was built for unsupported file format which
is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in /usr/lib/libogg.a, file was built for unsupported file format which
is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols:
  "_vorbis_info_init", referenced from:
      _main in ffconf.00FIGmPr.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: libvorbis not found
```

it looks like something to do with compiling libvorbis for x86_64? I just did a standard

```
./configure  && make && sudo make install
```

when I installed libvorbis, then I tried

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch x86_64"
```

and

```
./configure --build=x86_64
```

but nothing worked. All the other dependencies (libx264, libfaac libmp3lame etc) worked, just not libvorbis.

This is OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Snow Leopard, however on Lion 10.7.3 I used this for vorbis:

```
$ env CFLAGS="-O -g -arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64" ./configure --prefix=${TARGET} --with-ogg-libraries=${TARGET}/lib --with-ogg-includes=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw/include/ --enable-static --disable-shared && make -j 4 && make install
```

Comment: Can you explain what this command does?